# Arithmetic operations on arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to apply arithmetic operations on the values of an array in C. For example, if I want to add a number x to each value of an array, should I add it separately to each value, or instead can I add x to the whole array (so would it automaticaly add it to each value of the array).

Comment: Try yourself. If get any problem, bring here.

Comment: You have to add that number x for each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if I want to add a number x to each value of an array, should I add it separately to each value

Yes, you need to do it in a loop. C does not provide operators for manipulating the entire array at once.

> can I add x to the whole array

An expression that looks like adding an `int` to an array, e.g. `array+x`, will compile, but it is a different operation altogether: when an array name is used in an arithmetic operation, it is treated like a pointer to the initial element of the array, so the result of the `array+x` expression is the same as `&array[x]` (a pointer to element of `array` at index `x`).

Applying `+=` to an array would not compile.

Comment: "Adding an int to an array will compile, but it is a different operation altogether." What?

Comment: Switch is asking about `+=`, `+` does not match the question as-is.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, yes. For me "add to" would be the operator `+=` so I really was confused :)

Answer (score 2):

make a function that loops through your array and apply manualy your operation to each value contained in the array. There is no "buildin" function that will do that for you in C

Answer (score 0):

You have to run through the whole array like you would do in every language.

Comment: Some languages do support this. Matlab for example.

Comment: Yeah in a lot of language you have a map function or something equivalent but what happens under the wood is a loop through the whole array.

Comment: Well, the black box contains magic, however it works. (And the details are not of interest.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function that would handle that:

```
void Add(int* toIncrement, int size, int increaseBy){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        toIncrement[i] += increasedBy;
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
int thirteens[10] = {0};

Add(thirteens, 10, 13);
```

Note that if you wanted to write `Add` locally you could do that and avoid throwing a bunch of variables around.

Also if you wanted multiplication or something, just copy the function, change the function name and use `*=` in the place of `+=`.

Any modification of every element in an array is done this way in C.

Answer (score 0):

Here there is a simple example that can help to understand the concept of operations over arrays
    /*
    Basic Maths on arrays
    */

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int vector[] = {2, 4, 8, 3, 6};
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i = i + 1) 
    {
    vector[i] = vector[i]*3;
    Serial.println(vector[i]);
    }
  }
void loop()
{  
}
```